# How to get instagram media by location id or latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have used api.instagram to get media, but it returns me only:

```
{ data: [ ],
 meta: {
 code: 200
 } }
```

data is empty. I heart that instagram api works only by Facebook api. But I haven't find any documentation about media.
I need the help.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information to give an answer. Please post the code of the call...

Answer (score 1):

Instagram only supports graph API going forward, and the API to get media by location or lat/lng is no longer supported in graph API as of today.

Here is link to Instagram graph API documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/